# my theme dowsnt show previes and how to set my theme to post editor and page editor ?? - wordpress theme from scratch

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

im trying to make wordpress theme from scratch. how can my theme show the preview like other theme next to it ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoqN0.png)

and how to integrate my theme into editor ? post and page ??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQlSs.png)

I cant find any tutorial on google.

Answer (score 0):

**The first part is easy:**

You just need to make a preview image (the recommended image size is 1200px by 900px) and save it in PNG format. Important: Filename should be `screenshot.png`

Now just upload this file to your theme's main directory (the same place as style.css) and you're all set.

More info about theme screenshot can be found here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Screenshot

About the second part of your question ("how to integrate my theme into editor ? post and page?") please give more information about what you're trying to achieve.